# how to sync two mysql databases, when both of them have new entries

Tags: php, mysql, database, localhost, synchronization

I have mysql database installed on localhost for our local area network (a php application) and another copy of the same application and database for remote users is install on my online server.

There are several entries which have primary keys problem:  **scenario** if a user enters new record with primary key #4 on online server and on local server there is already a different record with primary key #4, so the application will run into problems.

**Note: I cannot put my local sever online due to limited bandwidth. So its out of question that I should use online server both for local and remote**

So can anyone tell me that how to sync both of my databases without getting into problem?

Comment: Use guids instead of incrementing integers.

Comment: There are two ways for doing sync first is told by @Matthew GUIDS but they have there own problems and another is you have to make one table as master who ever enters first would be given enter the data

Answer (score 3):

What I would recommend you to use, is MySQL Master-Master replication. I'm using it myself on my laptop and main computer to sync the MySQL databases with each other (both dev enviroments).

Lets say the online server is server 1, and the LAN server is server 2. The following code you should add to the my.ini file of MySQL on server 1

```
#Config for server 1
server-id=1
log-bin=mysql-logbin
log-slave-updates
replicate-same-server-id=0
auto_increment_increment=2
auto_increment_offset=1
report-host=#IP ADDRESS of server 1#
binlog-ignore-db=MySQL
```

and the my.ini file on server 2

```
#Config for server 2
server-id=2
log-bin=mysql-logbin
log-slave-updates
replicate-same-server-id=0
auto_increment_increment=2
auto_increment_offset=2
report-host=#IP ADDRESS of server 2#
binlog-ignore-db=MySQL
```

Than in phpmyadmin, you can create "replication" users. Add a user on server 1, and connect from server 2, with the user data of server 1, to server 1. Now server 2 is a slave of server 1. The opposite you also do: create a replication user on server 2, and add it to server 1. Now both servers are each other's master AND will stay in sync all the time!

The important thing to consider, is that the online server needs to be able to access the LAN server, so you might need to setup Network Address Translation or some port forwarding.

IF you don't want both servers in sync all the time, but want to get ride of the primary key problem, than just add this to the my.ini on both servers.

```
#Config for server 1
auto_increment_increment=2
auto_increment_offset=1

#Config for server 2
auto_increment_increment=2
auto_increment_offset=2
```

Now server 1 will only use 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11... as primary key, and server 2 will only use 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12... as primary key. That way your problem is solved.

Note: I find the best method to make Master-Master replication work, is by removing everything from the database, on both servers. Than reset all log files (this can be done manually by removing them from the "data" directory and editing a few numbers in other files), but can also be done via command (much saver). Than, setup the replication users. Since both servers are empty and have no logs, nothing happens. And last, add all databases to one of the servers, within a few seconds both of the databases should be in sync!

Good luck!